# descending sorting on hash values

Tags: ruby

Say, I have a hash which has elements like:

```
###EVNT-66  => 8.40, 
###EVNT-108 => 9.11,
###EVNT-345 => 88.22,
###EVNT-143 => 1.26
```

I wanted to sort them in descending order based on the hash values. So, I wrote this:

```
h.sort_by {|_key, value| value}.reverse
```

Surprisingly enough, I got results in this fashion:

```
###EVNT-108 => 9.11,
###EVNT-66  => 88.22,
###EVNT-345 => 8.40,
###EVNT-143 => 1.26
```

which is wrong. Line with '88' in it should be at the top. I am not sure what else could I write to achieve this.

Comment: The values are strings. If you want to sort them numerically instead of lexicographically, convert them to some numeric type either before or during sorting.

Comment: @Ryan, Thanks for the quick reply. So, how should I convert the string to numeric?

Comment: That depends. What kind of precision can your numbers have? Two decimal places, always between 0–100, or…?

Comment: I would have liked it for "two decimal places".

Comment: The convention for unused parameter is to use a single underscore `_` only.

Comment: When you give an example please present all inputs as valid Ruby objects. Also, it is helpful to assign a variable to each input. That way, readers can just cut-and-paste your code and reference the variables in comments and answers without having to define them. Here, for example, `h = { "###EVNT-66"  => "8.40",  "###EVNT-108" => "9.11", "###EVNT-345" => "88.22",  "###EVNT-143" => "1.26" }`.

Comment: @Mark, increasingly I see block variables like `_key`, presumably to convey more information than `_` alone. Like block variables `|_,_,b|`, Ruby has no problem with `|_a,_a, b|`, whereas shel'll raise an exception if she sees `|a,a,b|`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Hmm, some codebases (e.g. Rails core) generally use a leading underscore to denote a private variable, but that makes sense only at the instance (not local) scope, so I suppose it's not ambiguous here in a block variable. But I'm not sure you need to convey more information other than "this is an unused variable." However, if this is a burgeoning convention, I suppose I could get used to it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it seems sorted *alphabetically*. convert to numeric first.

```
h.sort_by {|_key, value| -value.to_f}
```

the minus sign could avoid the using of `reverse`

Comment: Worked like charm! Thanks. '.to_f' is what I needed.